# Is there any way to query the price of an item in a specific currency , in google IAP v 3.0 Android?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, android-pay

I have ran into a small problem here.I'm implementing some monetization tracking in my android application, and one of the 3rd party SDK-s offers this function:

```
public static void transactionInUSD(float priceInUSD, int quantity);
```

So here comes the question: Is there any way you can query `GoogleWallet` for the USD price of your items? ( As far as i got into the documentation, price/currency conversion is done automatically, and returned to you localized . )

Thank you very much!